# Necessary to keep snapshot when AMI exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I'm trying to keep my snapshot storage to a minimum.

I noticed when I create an AMI a snapshot also is created.

Can I safely delete the snapshot and still use the AMI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

When I went to delete the snapshot, I got the following message:

```
The snapshot snap-xxxx is currently in use by ami-xxxx
```

Comment: An AMI is just a logical object; it doesn't contain the bytes from your snapshot, it only references it, so you're not paying to store the same data twice.